# @ManagedProperty + @PostConstruct + init() = Nullpointer

Tags: spring, jsf, nullpointerexception, richfaces, postconstruct

Im getting a Nullpointer exception when using a managedProperty in my @PostConstruct - init() method as follows:

```
package mx.com.clubjava.pexapp.view.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


import mx.com.clubjava.pexapp.model.domain.Estado;
import mx.com.clubjava.pexapp.model.service.EstadoFacade;

@ManagedBean(name = "estadoSearchBean")
@ViewScoped
public class EstadoSearchBean implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4148160405036136787L;

    private List<Estado> estadoList;
    @ManagedProperty("#{estadoFacade}")
    private EstadoFacade estadoFacade;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        estadoList = estadoFacade.getEstados();
    }

    public List<Estado> getEstadoList() {
        return estadoList;
    }   

    public void setEstadoList(List<Estado> estadoList) {
        this.estadoList = estadoList;
    }

    public void setEstadoFacade(EstadoFacade estadoFacade) {
        this.estadoFacade = estadoFacade;
    }       

}
```

EstadoFacade class:

```
package mx.com.clubjava.pexapp.model.service.impl;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import mx.com.clubjava.pexapp.model.dao.EstadoDao;
import mx.com.clubjava.pexapp.model.domain.Estado;
import mx.com.clubjava.pexapp.model.service.EstadoFacade;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service(value = "estadoFacade")
@Transactional
@Scope( value= "request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES )
public class EstadoFacadeImpl implements EstadoFacade, Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3354568951955093044L;
    private List<Estado> estados;
    private EstadoDao estadoDao;    

    @PostConstruct
    private void prepareData() {
        estados = estadoDao.getAllActive();
    }   

    @Override
    public List<Estado> getEstados() {
        return estados;
    }

    @Override
    public Estado getEstadobyId(Long id) {
        Estado result = null;
        System.out.println("aqui va esto"+estados.size());
        for (int i = 0, j = estados.size(); i < j && result == null; i++) {
            Estado estado = estados.get(i);
            if (estado.getIdEstado() == id){
                result = estado;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setEstadoDao(EstadoDao estadoDao) {
        this.estadoDao = estadoDao;
    }   

}
```

Here is the error stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    mx.com.clubjava.pexapp.view.bean.EstadoSearchBean.init(EstadoSearchBean.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:68)
    org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:162)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:303)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:266)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:96)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85)
    javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243)
    javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:67)
    org.richfaces.component.util.SelectUtils$SelectItemsIterator.createUISelectItemsIterator(SelectUtils.java:226)
    org.richfaces.component.util.SelectUtils$SelectItemsIterator.createIterator(SelectUtils.java:244)
    org.richfaces.component.util.SelectUtils$SelectItemsIterator.computeNext(SelectUtils.java:168)
    org.richfaces.component.util.SelectUtils$SelectItemsIterator.computeNext(SelectUtils.java:145)
    com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectHelper.getConvertedSelectItems(SelectHelper.java:72)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectRendererBase.getConvertedSelectItems(SelectRendererBase.java:138)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.html.SelectRenderer.doEncodeEnd(SelectRenderer.java:182)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:180)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
    org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChild(RendererUtils.java:543)
    org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.renderChildren(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:315)
    org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:150)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:618)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1159)
    org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Im using richfaces 4.5.2 and spring 3.0.5.

I've also tried to inject EstadoFacade using @Autowire with same result, just dont know why injection is not working on PostContructed method...

Any help would be really appreciated I've been stuck almost two days with this isssue =(

Regards.

Comment: What annotations has `EstadoFacade` bean?

Comment: Hi Geinmachi.
@Service(value = "estadoFacade")
@Transactional
@Scope( value= "request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES )

Edited original post with complete class.

Comment: Then you shouldn't inject it with `@ManagedProperty` because it's not `JSF` bean. From docs: `If this annotation is present on a class that does not have the ManagedBean annotation, the implementation must take no action on this annotation.` Don't know anything about Spring, but you can try injecting it with `@Inject`, although `@Autowired` should work for Spring.

Comment: And your tags are misleading, there is no single line for RichFaces and you don't have Spring tag.

Comment: @geinmachi: you can 'edit' posts and suggest correct tags

Comment: Do you have the `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` registered in `faces-config.xml` as per Spring documentation?